# Matlab - conditional vector access

Tags: matlab

Sometimes I can see an index-access by condition, for example:

There's a vector `q = [a1, a2, a3, ... , an]`.

You can replace all the elements that equal 0 to 1 with the command `q(q == 0) = 1.`

You can count the elements that equals `1` by the command `sum(q == 1)`.

I'm not sure exactly how it works.. Can you please explain me this?

Comment: You should read up about logical indexing. For example [this MathWorks blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/)

Comment: [More here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

Comment: Note, that in case of `sum(q == 1)` `q == 1` is not and index, but a matrix of the same size as `q`.